# Hibernate Dialect version MSSQL for 2017

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to MSSQL Hibernate, Previously worked with MySQL implementation 
of Spring and hibernate.

I see the below supported list :

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

I can't find support for the latest version of 2017 MSSQL server. It's okay to work with org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect ?. Right now it works but i'm not sure how well it goes at a longer run.

Please suggest!

Thanks
Log.d

Comment: The latest hibernate dialect for MSSQL Server that you can use now is the `SQLServer2012Dialect`. Take a look a the available javadoc (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is okay to work with `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect` for SQL Server 2017. As far as I know, SQL Server 2012 Dialect is the latest support NHibernate has for SQLServer.

Source: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect